# How to split an image in blocks, based on a predefined mask

Tags: python, image

I have around 100 images that have a 5x5 grid, each grid cell contains a letter. I want to extract the sub-image of the letter from the main image to its corresponding subfolder (Letter A on image 1 lands in A/1.jpg ...).
The images can also have whitespace around, so I would like to minimize that whitespace somehow (maybe another letter is bigger then the other). After that I want to extract some features, so I think it would benefit the algorithms if the images are all the same size).

I've researched a bit, but haven't done much work with any sub-extraction. I know I could just define a mask or something similar in Numpy, but I'm wondering if there's a beter way. The images are always in the same position on all images.

I have tried something like this:

```
#parse PDF, for each page
#for each subblock (hardcoded width)    
subframe = image[currentPosX:subFrameWidth, currentPosY:subFrameHeight]
#save subframe in folder
```

But it introduces n^2 time complexity - I'm planning to run this on a low-powered machine, and probably the inputs could get a lot bigger. As mentioned above, I've been reading about using Numpy masks, but I'm kind of confused how to implement them.

Comment: question is going to get flagged -- too vague for this form. adding code and being more specific than "what's the best tool" will help